# VBA - Autofilter and copy visiable data to another feild

Tags: vba, autofilter

I have a dataset where I want to the VBA to do an auto-filter and in column B just unselect 0 and keep all the other values.

Then copy the visible cells to a new sheet. Can someone help me what the error is

Thanks

```
Sub findlastrowwithvaluefilter()
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CASCADE -Offshore Upload Format").Activate

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    With Range("A1:Q" & LastRow)
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Select All", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria1:="<>0"

        End With

    Range("A2:Q" & LastRow).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Q1" & LastRow).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

MsgBox (LastRow)

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get a runtime error?  If so, what does it say?  Does it give you the choice to `Debug or Continue`?  If `Debug` what line does it show the error?  If you can't debug, add a breakpoint to the first line and step through with F8 until you get an error.  What line is that on?  Please [edit these details into your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30761460/edit).  If it's not an actual error, can you tell us what it is doing/not doing vs. what is expected?

Comment: There is no error, what is happening is that the filter dosent select everything except 0. So Either it will select all when I remove the criteria, or will not select anything in the check-box

Comment: Should the second one be `Criteria2` instead of `Criteria1`?  If that doesn't do it, I'll take a look shortly.  Also does this work outside of VBA? If you manually set the filters?

Comment: Yes it works manually, I am trying to automate the process. So what I am trying to do is if in column B if they are zero I want to filter them out so only values are there, and then copy A to Q and get the last row from the macro .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Select All", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria1:="<>0"
```

with

```
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>0", Operator:=xlAnd
```

and should work

Comment: It the same issue as before, the filter will not select anything, so nothing is copied.

Comment: This should be the solution.  So something may be off up above.  What value is being returned for `LastValue`?  Using `SpecialCells` is not the best approach for this.  See [this discussion for alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba).  Note that `xlCellTypeLastCell` will ignore hidden rows so you want to clear any existing filter if you are coming in with one.  Inside your `With` add a `Debug.Print .Address` or `.Select` to see what range you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

it was a very small syntax issue. below is the working code.

The way to write the criteria so that zero is filtered out is

Criteria1:**=**"<>0". the = sign should be outside the parenthesis.

```
    Sub findlastrowwithvaluefilter()
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CASCADE -Offshore Upload Format").Activate

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row


    With Range("A1:Q" & LastRow)
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>0", Operator:=xlAnd
        End With

    Range("A2:Q" & LastRow).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Q1" & LastRow).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

MsgBox (LastRow)

End Sub
```